# ActiveRecord enum returning nil, even if it has a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums

I have an enum, which has a stored value, but the getter returns nil.

I have the following code:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum building_type:   [
    :none_building_type, :pre_war_low_rise, :pre_war_mid_rise,
    :pre_war_high_rise, :post_war_low_rise, :post_war_mid_rise,
    :post_war_high_rise, :pre_war_loft, :post_war_loft, :pre_war_hotel,
    :post_war_hotel
  ]
```

If I do the following in the console:

```
Property.last
```

I get

```
Property Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "properties".* FROM "properties"   ORDER BY "properties"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Property id: 3, created_at: "2014-11-17 15:39:34", updated_at: "2014-11-17 16:28:48", name: "PropertyName", property_type: 1, description: "adsdsaads", building_type: "4">
```

but If I do

```
Property.last.building_type
```

I get

```
 Property Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "properties".* FROM "properties"   ORDER BY "properties"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like your field type for the database entry of `building_type` is a String, instead of an Integer (which is what `enum` is mapping to according to the [documents](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)). Try to change the database schema and it should work.

Comment: @Anthony It's always the (metaphorical) semicolon that gets you!

Comment: wish i could give you a medal, I wouldn't have figured it out on my own even in a million years.